# run .py files on server - getting error 500

Tags: python, .htaccess, server

I'm trying to run simple python script in my server (hostgator) and I'm getting error 500 when run it in the url.

this is my .py file: (in public_html folder) CHMOD:755

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head>";
print "<title>CGI Test</title>";
print "</head><body>";
print "<p>Test page using Python</p>";
print "</body></html>";
```

and this is my .htaccess:  (in public_html folder)

```
AddType text/html py
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

Comment: Check your error logs

Comment: There is nothing on the error logs

Comment: You should not be getting nothing in the server error log if you are having a server error. Are you sure you're looking at the correct log file?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things that might be wrong:

- `AllowOverride FileInfo` is not set for this directory. 500 may indicate that apache has an issue with "malformed" `.htaccess`
- no executable bit on file:

  ```
   $ chmod +x my.py
  ```
- [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) gets in the way. Simple test for this is:

  ```
    $ SUEXEC=$(which suexec)
    $ mv ${SUEXEC} ${SUEXEC}.orig
    $ service httpd restart
  ```

In case of suEXEC there are several things you can do:

- trace the permissions and other items that might be preventing suexec from normal operation
- disable suexec completely by removing/renaming it's executable
- use ScriptAlias to define location for your scripts (this seems to sidestep suEXEC completely)

Comment: the chmod for the file is 755. Also I see in the cPanel Apache handler section that my .htaccess config are set.